# I've a function code written in oracle. want to make understanding of it

Tags: oracle

First create the `my_table` type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "MY_TABLE" AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(3000);
```

Then create the function

```
create or replace FUNCTION  "FUNC_STRING_TO_TABLE" (p_list IN VARCHAR2, p_delim IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN my_table
AS
    l_string       VARCHAR2(32767);
    l_comma_index  PLS_INTEGER;
    l_index        PLS_INTEGER := 1;
    l_tab          my_table := my_table();
BEGIN
    l_string := p_list ||p_delim;

    LOOP
      l_comma_index := INSTR(l_string, p_delim, l_index);
      EXIT WHEN l_comma_index = 0;
      l_tab.EXTEND;
      l_tab(l_tab.COUNT) := SUBSTR(l_string, l_index, l_comma_index - l_index);
      l_index := l_comma_index + 1;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN l_tab;
END FUNC_STRING_TO_TABLE;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see where the question is.  The function appears to take a string that has a delimited list of strings and convert it to a collection.  If you have APEX installed, there are built-in functions that already do this (i.e. `apex_string.split`).  Do you have some problem with the function or is there some part in particular that is confusing?

Comment: i just want to understand this whole function line by line

Comment: Which lines do you not understand?

Comment: the section after BEGIN.

Answer (score 1):

See the inline comments:

```sql
l_string := p_list ||p_delim;
-- Set l_string to be the input list with an extra delimiter appended.

LOOP
  -- Start a loop.
  l_comma_index := INSTR(l_string, p_delim, l_index);
  -- Find the position of the next comma in the string.
  EXIT WHEN l_comma_index = 0;
  -- Exit the loop when a comma was not found.
  l_tab.EXTEND;
  -- Extend the l_tab collection by 1 element.
  l_tab(l_tab.COUNT) := SUBSTR(l_string, l_index, l_comma_index - l_index);
  -- Set the last element of the l_tab collection to the substring
  -- between the last comma and the next comma.
  l_index := l_comma_index + 1;
  -- Skip to the position in the string after the next comma.
END LOOP;
-- Restart the loop.

RETURN l_tab;
-- Return the collection.
```